# FullCalendar showing too many weeks

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

I have an instance of full calendar running on my asp.net site but it keep showing too many weeks. Such as not it is showing 6 weeks even tho there are only 5 weeks in November

Comment: isn't this just standard behaviour, set to cope with months that do span 6 weeks (e.g. Aug 2010)? That way, the month view will always show 6 weeks rather than flicking being 5 or 6, as users step through different months.

Comment: @richaux, no, per the documentation it is supposed to change between 4, 5, or 6 weeks depending on the month by using the "WeekMode" variable. I have tried "liquid" and "variable" Neither seem to change it to 5 weeks.    http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/weekMode/

Comment: if you use "variable", November 2010 should display 5 weeks. if it doesn't, please post a bug report to the issue tracker (http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list) and make sure to include a working demonstration of the problem

Answer (score 4):

You just have to set `fixedWeekCount: false` that should do the trick, it will show the correct amount of weeks by month.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/